# Android XBMC remote: Java error: FileNotFoundException (command=getSystemInfo)

Tags: android, remote, kodi, raspberry-pi, raspbmc

I want to use my raspberryPI as a HTPC. I installed [Raspbmc](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Raspbmc) and tried to connect to it via [Official XBMC Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xbmc.android.remote) but I get the error:

```
I/O Exception (java.io.FileNotFoundException)
http://192.168.178.27:8080/xbmcCmds/xbmcHttp?command=getSystemInfo (120)
```

The remote control works, but it's annoying because the error pops up on every action I take. Any suggestions why I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is as simple as disappointing. XBMC v12 is beta and just not supported by the official XBMC remote yet, which is itself still! a beta version.

*Edit*

For everyone facing this error: [xbian](http://xbian.org/) is a way better xbmc distro and [YATSE](http://xbian.org/) is the way better remote.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your service settings. I've seen similar errors when both the webserver and remote control functions are not enabled. Be sure the webserver is on AND the remote control service is enabled with the option to allow other systems to control XBMC.

```
Settings > Services > Webserver
Settings > Services > Remote control
```

Comment: They are both activated.

Answer (score 0):

[Yatse XBMC remote for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.leetzone.android.yatsewidgetfree) works great with XBMC Frodo v12.